# How to tar xf glib-*.tar.gz correctly?

Tags: bash, 22.04, tar, glib

I downloaded glib-2.76.3.tar.xz from https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.76/

Extracted the file and opened the INSTALL.md inside of it.

Here's an excerpt of it:

````
Simple install procedure
========================

```sh
tar xf glib-*.tar.gz                    # unpack the sources
cd glib-*                               # change to the toplevel directory
meson _build                            # configure the build
ninja -C _build                         # build GLib

# Become root if necessary

ninja -C _build install                 # install GLib
````

I ran `sh` on terminal, but when I run `tar xf glib-*.tar.gz` it throws error:

```
tar: glib-*.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

As I understand I have to write something instead of the `*` but I don't know what exactly.

`tar xf glib-2.76.3.tar.gz` throws the same type of error. Maybe I'm in the wrong directory also?

Comment: If you downloaded the `.xz` compressed archive rather than the `.gz` compressed archive, your need to modify the filename in the `tar` command accordingly i.e. `tar xf glib-*.tar.xz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is clearly wrong on several details, since it states a `.gz` extension, but the actual file has an `.xz` extension.

So if you're in the directory where the file is located, you can run:

```
tar xf glib-*.tar.xz
```

Or you can run the exact filename:

```
tar xf ./glib-2.76.3.tar.xz
```

Instead of the `.` you can also specify the full path, like this:

```
tar xf /path/to/glib-2.76.3.tar.xz
```

Also for the next command (`cd`) use: (here the `cd glib-*` will not work)

```
cd glib-2.76.3
```

Or full path again:

```
cd /path/to/glib-2.76.3
```

I cases like this, documentation should be seen as guidance, that can contain errors - always double check with common sense.

Comment: Note that using the wildcard for the tarball assumes there's only one matching filename. It might work with `cd` too if you append a trailing slash, that should make the shell match only directories (thus skipping the tarball), i.e. `cd glib-*/`.