# Building GLib using command ninja -C _build failed

Tags: glib

While installing GLib based on INSTALL.md guide from https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.76/ (continued from here -> [How to tar xf glib-*.tar.gz correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470127/how-to-tar-xf-glib-tar-gz-correctly/1470128#1470128))

I typed to the terminal `ninja -C _build` 
And while building got an error:

```
ninja: Entering directory `_build'
[980/1499] Generating gio/tests/plugin-resources.c with a custom command
FAILED: gio/tests/plugin-resources.c 
/home/User/Desktop/GLib/glib-2.76.3/_build/gio/glib-compile-resources --compiler=gcc --target=gio/tests/plugin-resources.c --sourcedir=/home/User/Desktop/GLib/glib-2.76.3/gio/tests --internal --generate-source --c-name _g_plugin ../gio/tests/test4.gresource.xml
/home/User/Desktop/GLib/glib-2.76.3/_build/gio/glib-compile-resources: symbol lookup error: /home/User/Desktop/GLib/glib-2.76.3/_build/gio/glib-compile-resources: undefined symbol: g_task_set_static_name
[989/1499] Compiling C object gio/test...required-2-64.p/gdbus-test-codegen.c.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Where does this error come from and how to fix it?

Comment: The symbol should be defined in the build's own `./_build/gio/libgio-2.0.so.0.7600.0` file, so the error suggests that was not built correctly (or not built at all). You might get some additional information if you start over and run ninja with the verbose flag (`ninja -C _build/ --verbose`). However you might want to consider one of [the alternative routes I suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470114/how-to-update-glib-repository-to-at-2-76-3#comment2576725_1470114).